# Beginner Python programmer here, struggling to use the logical OR operator

Tags: python

Wrote the code snippet below on the Python IDLE and got the proper answer below:

```
>>> cars = ["audi", "bmw", "daimler", "toyota", "vw"]
>>> for car in cars:
    if "a" in car:
        print(car.title())
    else:
        print(car.upper())
```

RESULT:

```
Audi
BMW
Daimler
Toyota
VW
```

Then I changed the code so I could print the cars with no vowel UPPER and the rest Title as shown below but I got all cars printed Title:

```
>>> cars = ["audi", "bmw", "daimler", "toyota", "vw"]
>>> for car in cars:
    if "a" or "e" in car:
        print(car.title())
    else:
        print(car.upper())
```

RESULT:

```
Audi
Bmw
Daimler
Toyota
Vw
```

Can someone kindly help tell what is wrong with the last block of code, the goal is to print all cars without vowel fully uppercase and the rest as Title.

Thank you.

Comment: That is not how `or` should be used. It should be like so: `if "a" in car or "e" in car:`

Comment: `p or q` is equivalent to `p if p else q` or in your case `"a" if "a" else ("e" in car)`, so taking into account that `"a"` is "trueish", the expression will always return `"a"`.

Comment: Thank you @Anwarvic for help in editing the post. Perhaps you can guide me on how to make future posts correctly. Appreciate it Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if "a" or "e" in car` will be always `True` since `a` is logically `True`.
Try instead:

```
if "a" in car or "e" in car:
    print(car.title())
else:
   print(car.upper())
```

or you can use `any` if you would like to check more chars and want to avoid multiple `or`s:

```
# any will return True if `car` contains one of the chars in the provided list.
if any(map(lambda c: c in car,["a","e"])):
    print(car.title())
else:
   print(car.upper())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very useful reply. Now I see the sense in your answer. Still a beginner and will get to lambda soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression:

```
"a" or "e" in car
```

is equivalent to:

```
"a" or ("e" in car)
```

which is *always* `"a"`, a truthy value. That's why it's executing `title()` on everything.

You should instead be using:

```
if "a" in car or "e" in car
```

or (half jokingly), since every problem can be solved by throwing more regular expressions at it:

```
if re.search("[ae]", car) is not None: # needs import re
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very useful. Got it done now.

Answer (score 0):

TBH you are not very clear with or statements no problem but this is the desired way of passing the or in if statement i have made the code for you.

```
cars = ["audi", "bmw", "daimler", "toyota", "vw"]
for car in cars:
    if "a" in car or 'e' in car or 'i' in car or 'o' in car or 'u' in car:
        print(car.title())
    else:
        print(car.upper())
```

The output is:

```
Audi
BMW
Daimler
Toyota
VW

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very useful. Got it done now.